# Playing an mp3-file with libsox

Tags: linux, file, mp3, playback

I have an application in which I need to play an mp3 file. What I'm looking for is some kind of wrapper functions for libsox (or any other audio lib). I have been looking all over the net but have not found any option that is fast to implement. I'm looking for something like;

bla=open_file("/mnt/music/my_music.mp3")

play_thefile(bla)

stop_thefile(bla)

close_thefile(bla)

I just want it simple this time, no crazy mixing or filter stuff. Anyone know of something that would help?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up sugin libmpd0 in combination with MPD, this works very well and libmpd is extremly easy to use.